# Excel VBA: nome do objeto (Label) na célula

Tags: vba

No excel, Tenho um botão no formulário, que vai mudar o caption de um label no mesmo formulário. Porém, tenho 22 labels nesse formulário. Qual label quero que a ação seja executada é variável e está definido numa célula a planilha.

```
Dim LabelAtual As string:   LabelAtual = Range("A10").Value              'O valor na A10 é "LBL7" = o nome do label para editar.

Me.LabelAtual.Object = "Maria Carolina"
```

Não funciona, não está entendendo que LabelAtual é, nesse momento, LBL7. Talvez não seja string? Se alguém puder ajudar, desde já obrigado.

Comment: Da forma que eu fiz abaixo funcionou no meu excel.

Comment: O código que você coloca está no próprio form, ou está em um módulo separado?

Comment: Tente o seguinte: `LabelAtual = Me.Controls(Range("A10").Value)`. Diga se funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso basta inserir o código abaixo depois abrir um formulario (UserForm1), com um Botão (CommandButton1) e depois um Rotulo (Label1). Depois é só clicar duas vezes no Botão e inserir todo codigo abaixo:

```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

     Dim LabelAtual As String:   LabelAtual = Range("A10").Value

     Label1.Caption = LabelAtual


   End Sub
```

Depois de executar é só clicar no Botão que o Rótulo (Label1) assume o valor que estiver na célula A10;